# How can I get the interface name/index associated with a TCP socket?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I'm writing a TCP server that needs to know which interface each connection arrived from. I cannot use the address/subnet to deduce which interface was used, since there might be interfaces with the same address/subnet values. It's Linux based, and there's no need for the code to be portable.

All I could find were functions to get all interfaces, or a single interface by index. I could not find any way to get the interface associated with an accepted TCP socket.

Any ideas? Something I've missed?

EDIT: To reiterate, IP addresses are not unique in my case. Neither the destination addresses (the server itself) nor the source addresses (the clients).
Yes, this is a very extreme IP scheme.

Comment: The only correct answer here, given that you're looking for code to add to your server, is the one from User1. I've tested it, and it works - you should accept it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43659634/find-the-interface-used-by-a-connected-socket/43663713#43663713

Comment: @EML There is no User1 at the moment.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam: not sure, but I think it must be SKi. I upvoted him, and the code looks familiar.

Answer (score 13):

Use `getsockname()` to get IP of local end of the TCP connection.
Then use `getifaddrs()` to find the corresponding interface:

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
struct ifaddrs* ifaddr;
struct ifaddrs* ifa;
socklen_t addr_len;

addr_len = sizeof (addr);
getsockname(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &addr_len);
getifaddrs(&ifaddr);

// look which interface contains the wanted IP.
// When found, ifa->ifa_name contains the name of the interface (eth0, eth1, ppp0...)
for (ifa = ifaddr; ifa != NULL; ifa = ifa->ifa_next)
{
    if (ifa->ifa_addr)
    {
        if (AF_INET == ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family)
        {
            struct sockaddr_in* inaddr = (struct sockaddr_in*)ifa->ifa_addr;

            if (inaddr->sin_addr.s_addr == addr.sin_addr.s_addr)
            {
                if (ifa->ifa_name)
                {
                    // Found it
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
freeifaddrs(ifaddr);
```

Above is just a dirty example, some modifications are needed:

1. Add missing error checks
2. IPv6 support

Comment: Note that this `if (inaddr->sin_addr.s_addr == addr.sin_addr.s_addr)` probably never matches. I would suggest you apply the netmask to improve chances a tad bit: `if (inaddr->sin_addr.s_addr == (addr.sin_addr.s_addr & ((struct sockaddr_in*)ifa->ifa_netmask)->sin_addr.s_addr))`

Comment: @AlexisWilke : We have used this kind of if-statement in production software for years without problems. I don't understood why it would not match to any item in the list, because `inaddr` contains local (not peer or sub-net) IP address.

Comment: Right, in my case I want to find the interface that corresponds to any address, so I could have 192.168.3.111 which won't match 192.168.3.0 unless I first apply the mask of the interface.

Comment: Multiple interfaces can belong to the same IP network, multiple interface can even have the same IP address. Which interface is being used to send traffic can only be determined by looking at the routing table.

Answer (score 5):

Here's some C++11 code to find the interface name of a socket:

```
std::string to_string(sockaddr_in const& addr)
{
    char buf[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, &addr.sin_addr, buf, sizeof(buf)) == nullptr)
    {
        std::clog << "inet_ntop: " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
        return {};
    }
    return buf;
}

std::string to_string(sockaddr_in6 const& addr)
{
    char buf[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    if (inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &addr.sin6_addr, buf, sizeof(buf)) == nullptr)
    {
        std::clog << "inet_ntop: " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
        return {};
    }
    return buf;
}

std::string to_string(sockaddr_storage const& addr, socklen_t len)
{
    switch (addr.ss_family)
    {
    case AF_INET:
    {
        auto& a = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in const&>(addr);
        if (len < sizeof(a))
        {
            std::clog << "Invalid sockaddr length: " << len << '\n';
            return {};
        }
        return to_string(a);
    }
    case AF_INET6:
    {
        auto& a = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6 const&>(addr);
        if (len < sizeof(a))
        {
            std::clog << "Invalid sockaddr length: " << len << '\n';
            return {};
        }
        return to_string(a);
    }
    default:
    {
        std::clog << "Invalid sockaddr family: " << addr.ss_family << '\n';
        return {};
    }
    }
}

std::string get_iface_name(sockaddr_in const& addr)
{
    ifaddrs *ifa = nullptr;
    if (getifaddrs(&ifa) == -1)
    {
        std::clog << "getifaddrs: " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
        return {};
    }
    std::unique_ptr<ifaddrs, void(*)(ifaddrs*)>
        finally{ifa, freeifaddrs};

    for (; ifa; ifa = ifa->ifa_next)
    {
        if (!ifa->ifa_addr)
            continue;
        if (!ifa->ifa_name)
            continue;
        if (ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family != AF_INET)
            continue;
        auto& a = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in&>(*ifa->ifa_addr);
        if (a.sin_addr.s_addr == addr.sin_addr.s_addr)
            return ifa->ifa_name;
    }

    std::clog << "No interface found for IPv4 address " << to_string(addr) << '\n';
    return {};
}

std::string get_iface_name(sockaddr_in6 const& addr)
{
    ifaddrs *ifa = nullptr;
    if (getifaddrs(&ifa) == -1)
    {
        std::clog << "getifaddrs: " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
        return {};
    }
    std::unique_ptr<ifaddrs, void(*)(ifaddrs*)>
        finally{ifa, freeifaddrs};

    for (; ifa; ifa = ifa->ifa_next)
    {
        if (!ifa->ifa_addr)
            continue;
        if (!ifa->ifa_name)
            continue;
        if (ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family != AF_INET6)
            continue;
        auto& a = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6&>(*ifa->ifa_addr);
        if (memcmp(a.sin6_addr.s6_addr,
                   addr.sin6_addr.s6_addr,
                   sizeof(a.sin6_addr.s6_addr)) == 0)
            return ifa->ifa_name;
    }

    std::clog << "No interface found for IPv6 address " << to_string(addr) << '\n';
    return {};
}

std::string get_iface_name(sockaddr_storage const& addr, socklen_t len)
{
    switch (addr.ss_family)
    {
    case AF_INET:
    {
        auto& a = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in const&>(addr);
        if (len < sizeof(a))
        {
            std::clog << "Invalid sockaddr length: " << len << '\n';
            return {};
        }
        return get_iface_name(a);
    }
    case AF_INET6:
    {
        auto& a = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6 const&>(addr);
        if (len < sizeof(a))
        {
            std::clog << "Invalid sockaddr length: " << len << '\n';
            return {};
        }
        return get_iface_name(a);
    }
    default:
    {
        std::clog << "Invalid sockaddr family: " << addr.ss_family << '\n';
        return {};
    }
    }
}

std::string get_iface_name(int sockfd)
{
    sockaddr_storage addr;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);
    if (getsockname(sockfd, (sockaddr*)&addr, &len) == -1)
    {
        std::clog << "getsockname: " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
        return {};
    }
    std::clog << "getsockname '" << to_string(addr, len) << '\'' << '\n';
    return get_iface_name(addr, len);
}
```

Comment: Fails if I set a route for the detonation address to point to a different interface. The process for deciding which interface traffic will take is named routing and the routing table is the relevant data source.

Answer (score 4):

In general, you shouldn't need to know what interface the packets are going to be sent/received on; that's the kernel's routing table's job. It's difficult to find out the interface for a socket because there really is no direct association. The routing of packets can change within the socket's lifetime based on routing information.

For datagram (UDP) sockets, you may be able to use `getsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_PKTINFO, ...)`; see `getsockopt(2)` and `ip(7)`.

For stream (TCP) sockets, one option might be to open multiple listening sockets, one for each interface on the system, and use `setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, ...)` to bind each to one interface;  see `setsockopt(2)` and `socket(7)`.

Comment: Yes, setting separate socket for each interface would work, but seeing as there are dozens of interfaces and they are brought up and taken down dynamically, it's something I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel routing table decides which interface to send a packet out on, hence the ability to bond devices. A cursory glance through "Linux Socket Programming, Warren W. Gay" suggests that specifying an interface is bad, and that due to the dynamics of the kernel (firewall, forwarding) it is more complex.

I would suggest altering your IP scheme such that the IP information tells you your interface(s) through looking up in the same way ifconfig does, otherwise you are shooting yourself in the foot design wise.

1) Get the IP information from the TCP session
2) Lookup which interface(s) this could be valid for

I will keep looking in the kernel API though. You shouldn't need to know this, the abstraction is there for a multitude of good reasons.

**Extra Thought**
Pondering on this, it seems that if both interfaces use the same IP then there must be a client address range routing difference (otherwise both interfaces would be used). Your server could examine the routing table based on the client IP

Comment: The client IPs can overlap as well. The difference that allows these IPs to overlap is the VLAN id. As far as I know, that's inaccessible as well.

Comment: you may have found the one situation where you can't use circumstantial evidence to determine interface. I don't think there will be a way, as the interface is kind of abstract from applications higher than the kernel. You could maybe modify your kernel to provide some data through /proc/tcp_sessions_to_devs or something but that is VERY - erm - desperate?

Comment: Another thought. Trying looking into the interface sniffing libraries that Wireshark uses (libpcap) and look at how the source of iftop enumerates sessions on a device. Might be interesting.

Comment: You can only determine the interface by looking at the routing table, not at the interface configuration. Despite the fact at that multiple interfaces may be attached to the same IP network, multiple interface can even have the same IP address. And regardless which interface traffic would usually take, I can always add a route and force it over a different interface. It's the routing table that decides which interface a packet will leave the system and nobody else. Interface settings just create entries in the routing table but only the table knows the truth.

Answer (score 1):

I think using getsockname() after accept()ing the incoming connection might be what you're after. The two functions getsockname() and getpeername() get the local and remote addresses respectively that a socket is bound to. Both should be valid for a fully connected TCP socket.

Edit: Whilst this seems to be true for OpenBSD according to the man page, the Linux man page differs considerably and so getsockname() after accept() on Linux is almost certainly unuseful. Teaches me for using my memory instead of checking everything. *sigh*

Comment: actually, i tried it and this solution works in linux and windows

Comment: Wrong 'name' - this returns the *address*. The OP wants the interface name, ie. eth0/etc. As the glibc docs say, "the functions and symbols for dealing with socket addresses were named inconsistently, sometimes using the term 'name', and sometimes using 'address'".

Answer (score 0):

Look at the destination address.

Each interface is normally bound to a unique address. If multiple interfaces are bonded together, it probably doesn't matter which one it used.

The only exception to this, is when using ipv6 anycast, but even then, you wouldn't normally have multiple interfaces on the same host with the same ip.

Comment: In this case, the interfaces are not bound to unique addresses. They are not bonded either. They are connected to different networks, although they have overlapping/identical IPs.

Comment: If you have a tcp connection, you must have an ip address. You don't have to bind a socket to a particular address, but your interface needs one

Comment: Yes, the connection has an IP address, but it's not unique. It's not unique for that interface, and it's not unique for that network. I really need a way to get the interface from the socket itself.

Comment: It seems you have an unusual case. I'll leave my answer as is, as it's logical for most people's cases, and @Aiden answered with what I was going to add.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously not something I've looked into very deeply, let alone tried, this might be one for the "so crazy it just might work" basket...

If it's really only ever going to be for Linux, you could write a custom [netfilter](http://www.netfilter.org/) module which tracks the incoming connections and notes which interface they come in on, and writes that information somewhere for your server application to read.

Answer (score 0):

Kieron's suggestion to write a netfilter module is probably one way to try, but I would like to refrain from writing my very first kernel module for this solution.

I've come up with another option of using source NAT and translating the source port of the connection to correlate with the connection source. I can assign port ranges for each network and check it in the server. The only problem is that source NAT in iptables is done in the POSTROUTING chain, and I'm not sure it's used for connections that are accepted by that host, so I might need to use another server.

No easy solutions here, too bad I can't get the interface name/index from the socket...

Comment: Another netfilter option is to forward the traffic to additional local interfaces that have been set up with distinct IP adresses.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding another answer and a potential solution after looking through the source of Wireshark and iftop which seem to have indirectly similar functionality.

Looks to me that you can use libpcap to sniff on interfaces. Presuming you can identify some unique part of the TCP/IP session then you can track it down to an interface fairly simply using filters and session tracking.

No kernel modules (and it plays nice with threads)

http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/ Some simple source to have a peek at
www.tcpdump.org/ for libpcap

I think you will be able to match VLANs using it too.

Also wireshark might be useful for debugging. Hope this helps! It's been on my brain since.

Comment: Yep, that sounds like another option. Thanks for the effort!