# How to get local MAC address from connected socket?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

Assuming that a TCP connection was succesfully established, how to get a local MAC address associated with it?

```
int fd = ::socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
::sockaddr_in tgt = { AF_INET, ::htons (443), { 0x08080808 } };
::connect (fd, &tgt, sizeof (tgt));
```

I've seen solutions based on first obtaining a local IP address from the socket and then obtaining a MAC address by that IP address, but they are error prone: if there are multiple interfaces with the same IP address, such solutions can't distinguish between them.

Comment: `/sys/class/net/*/address`

Comment: Sockets aren't associated with a specific interface. If there are multiple interfaces with the same IP, any of them can be used to receive packets.

Comment: @273K The duplicate you chose is about getting the remote MAC address, not the local MAC.

Comment: And outgoing packets don't even have to use the interface with the local IP of the socket. The outgoing interface depends on the remote IP, not the local IP.

Comment: @ted-lyngmo, how do i get network interface from the socket?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63899229/how-to-find-the-network-interface-used-by-a-connected-socket

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What do you need the MAC address for?

Comment: @barmar which returns us to original problem: we can't distinguish multiple interfaces with the same IP address.

Comment: @Barmar, this is characteristic that our system uses in multiple internal algorithms.

Comment: From my research, you can't have two interfaces with the same IP, unless they're in different namespaces.

Comment: Multiple MACs with the same IP will result in a very interesting system to troubleshoot. Not sure how you've gotten into this position, but I wish you luck in getting out of it.

Comment: @barmar yes, but then comes another question: how to get socket's network namespace? The only thing I found so far is kernel-level `sock_net`.

Comment: _this is characteristic that our system uses in multiple internal algorithms_ This does not answer the question posed