# Linux socket ioctl SIOCGIFNAME No such device error

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ioctl

I'm trying to get interface name via `ioctl`:

```
int sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
struct sockaddr_in addr = { 0 };
struct ifreq if_req = { 0 };

if (sock_fd == -1) {
    perror("socket error");
    return -1;
}

addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.136");

if (bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
    perror("bind error");
    return -1;
}

if (ioctl(sock_fd, SIOCGIFNAME, &if_req) == -1) {
    perror("ioctl error");
    return -1;
}

printf("name: %s\nip: %s\n",
                if_req.ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name,
                inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr)
);
```

But for some reason `ioctl` fails with `No such device` error message. I wonder what is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html), we find the following description for `SIOCFIFNAME`:

> Given the `ifr_ifindex`, return the name of the interface in
> `ifr_name`.  This is the only ioctl which returns its result
> in `ifr_name`.

In your code, you're initializing `ifreq` like this:

```
struct ifreq if_req = { 0 };
```

So all the values -- including `if_req.ifr_ifindex` -- are 0. You're
asking for the interface name of the device with index 0, but there is
no such device. On my system, for example, `lo` is index 1 and `eth0`
is index 2:

```
$ ip -o link
1: lo: ...
2: eth0: ...
```

That number at the beginning of each line is the interface index.

You may want to take a look at [How can I get the interface name/index associated with a TCP socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848040/how-can-i-get-the-interface-name-index-associated-with-a-tcp-socket), which has some suggestions for mapping a socket to an interface name.